# Creating Pivot Table using poi java

Tags: pivot-table, xlsx

I am creating pivot table in xlsx using poi and java.Here i have some questions,Please let me know if you guys know any solutions.
My Code is below

```
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet();
    XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(new AreaReference("A1:E4"), new CellReference("H5"));
    pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
    pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 1);
```

Manually , we can create pivot the data in xlsx.But using poi, I feel some difficulties.

To add Fields in "Page Fields", addReportFilter can be used.
To add Fields in "Row Fileds", addRowLabel can be used
To add Fileds in "Data Fields", addColumnLabel can be used
To add Fields in "Column Fields", Which method can we use? Is there any option ?

And there is a method, "addDataColumn". I can't understand the purpose of this method.While trying it,i didn't get anything.

Please help me...